# how to get value of multiple checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have to get values of multiple checkbox checked in AngularJS. I have to use that value in **Controller.js**.What can i do for this?
I set the value in ng-model but It has given null array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your model :

```
{"cars":
  [
    {"v":"m","n":"Mini","c":false},
    {"v":"c","n":"Corvette","c":true},
    {"v":"b","n":"BMW","c":true},
    {"v":"l","n":"Lamborghini","c":true},
    {"v":"f","n":"Ferrari","c":false}
  ]
}
```

you want only checked :

```
$scope.brands = $filter('filter')($scope.viewModel, {c: true});
```

see http://plnkr.co/edit/PnABre?p=preview